# REGEX in MYSQL Query to find the string

Tags: mysql, regex

I am not familar in REGEX command in mysql

Ineed to find all records structured like this

```
Initcap lowercase $specificstring
```

This would include all cases of `UC lc1-N software`

e.g

```
Database modeling software
3D animation and modeling software
```

as well as any `Initcap lc1-N UC software`

e.g

```
Storage area network SAN software
```

In same vein also need to find this structure

Boundary scan description language BSDL

```
Initcap lowercase1-N UC
```

where letters in `UC` equal `# of previous words`. I don't mind doing manually

e.g

```
Init lc lc [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]
Init lc lc lc [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]
```

since there are a *finite # of cases*

Finally I also need to find cases like AbcDef e.g ClimateMaster

I need to have these available to mysql queries.

Regards
Vikram

Comment: it looks like you're just grabbing anything that ends with `software`

Answer (score 0):

**Initcap lowercase $specificstring**

```
^[A-Z\d]\w+\s+[a-z]+\s+.+$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Discussion

You will find debuggex.com useful for testing your regular expressions before runing them into Mysql.

You can start here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ovpg4009G0KVlSL9, for your other regular expressions.